# Rails query database and store into variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I've been reading through documentation in the rails guides and I cant seem to find an answer on how to do this.

I want to be able to query a specific column in my model and store it into a variable. i think the best thing I can do is write the SQL query to explain it.

Here's my controller definition

```
  def upvote
    @request = Request.find(params[:request_id]) # Do you still need this ?


    @requestID = Request.find(params[:id])
    @requestEmail = Request.where(id: @requestID).select(:email)


    @request.email = current_user.email
    @requestNewEmail = @request.email + ', ' +  @requestEmail
    @request.email = @requestNewEmail

    @request.increment!(:voteCount)
    @request.save
    render json: { voteCount: @request.voteCount , email: @request.email}
  end
```

Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

```
SELECT email FROM requests WHERE id = requestID
```

Everything I've tried either returns the error `Couldn't find Request without an ID`

Or `no implicit conversion from Request to string`

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? from what I can understand you are trying to add current_user 's email to @request.email and increment the `@request.vote_count`. what are you assigning to `@requestID = ` & `@requestEmail =`

Comment: `@request = Request.find(params[:request_id])` -> `Couldn't find Request without an ID`, can you look at params if you're getting the value for `request_id`? Could it be just `id`?

Comment: the `.increment` line works right now. I'm trying to add a second piece of functionality where it takes the logged in user's email address and concatenates it with whatever is already in that field in the database. So, I'll grab the email address, grab the current user's email address and concatenate them with a comma delimiter. I have no idea whether this is the best way to accomplish what im trying to, but thinking through it in a linear fashion, this seemed like the most obvious route.

Comment: I updated the code to show what I'm trying that's giving me the error. I didn't realize I left it out when I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Posting as answer because comment space would not be sufficient. This can be improved with better understanding of requirements.

The error `no implicit conversion from Request to string` occurs when we try to concatenate `@requestEmail` with a string. This line to be precise:

```
@requestNewEmail = @request.email + ', ' +  @requestEmail
```

This is because we fetch `@requestEmail` using this query:

```
@requestEmail = Request.where(id: @requestID).select(:email)
```

What this does is that it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Something like `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Request id: nil, email: <some_email>>]>`. This is an array, and we could fetch the first email from it using `@requestEmail.first.email` and then concatenate it with the string.
However, in your code you've already fetched the required record as

```
@requestID = Request.find(params[:id])
```

This could be used to get the required email value instead of making another DB call. That is, `@requestID.email` itself, would give you the value that you're trying to fetch using `@requestEmail = Request.where(id: @requestID).select(:email)` 
I think the overall code could be simplified if the requirements are a little clearer. Maybe you could explain in detail what's trying to be achieved? This current answer would probably solve the error, but I believe there could be a better way to achieve your requirements since this entire block feels a bit off.
Please feel free to comment explaining further details.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a method in the Request model and use it in the controller action

```
# app/models/request.rb
def add_email(new_email)
  update(email: email + ', ' + new_email)
end

# controller/requests_controller.rb
def upvote
  @request = Request.find(params[:request_id]) 
  @request.add_email(current_user.email)
end
```